# get back hidden FORM from another FORM

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms `Form1` and `Form2`

I am opening `Form2` from `Form1` on `button_Click`

```
Form2 obj2 = new Form2();
this.Visible = false;
obj2.Show();
```

then I want to get back `Form1` Visible **(on disposing `Form2`)** in same states of Controls on which I left.....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your `Form2` doesn't know anything about `Form1`. It will need a reference to it (you can do that by adding a `Form` type property on `Form2` and assign `Form1` to it after construction):

```
//In Form2
public Form RefToForm1 { get; set;}

//In Form1
Form2 obj2 = new Form2();
obj2.RefToForm1 = this;
this.Visible = false;
obj2.Show();

//In Form2, where you need to show Form1:
this.RefToForm1.Show();
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, personally I would pass the reference via the constructor but that's just two different shades of the same color. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oded's answer will work perfectly well, another option with the same result will be to expose public event in Form2 called for example "AfterClose", invoke it when Form2 is disposing and have Form1 add event handler where it show itself. Let me know if you're interested and I'll give some sample code.

Comment: i would like to knw hw 2 show hidden form at current state(when hidden) from another form.